# AWS Elastic Beanstalk fails deployment because of NPM warnings

Tags: node.js, npm, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My elastic beanstalk deployment fails with this log

```
2021/03/23 14:42:05.458565 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [config-deploy] - [Use NPM to install dependencies]. Stop running the command. Error: Command /bin/sh -c npm --production install failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:npm WARN deprecated babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.2.0: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797 )
npm WARN deprecated is-hex@1.1.3: Development of this module has been stopped.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142 
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@2.1.3: "Please update to latest v2.3 or v2.2"
npm WARN deprecated request@2.16.6: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142 
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797 )
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated hawk@0.10.2: This module moved to @hapi/hawk. Please make sure to switch over as this distribution is no longer supported and may contain bugs and critical security issues.
npm WARN deprecated hoek@0.7.6: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated cryptiles@0.1.3: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated boom@0.3.8: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated sntp@0.1.4: This module moved to @hapi/sntp. Please make sure to switch over as this distribution is no longer supported and may contain bugs and critical security issues.
npm WARN deprecated json3@3.2.6: Please use the native JSON object instead of JSON 3
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.1: Use uuid module instead
```

This should not cause the platform to fail the deployment.

Is there a way to override the ELB `npm install` command to add the `--logLevel=error` flag.

Still feels like a bug with ELB even if its possible to ignore the warnings somehow.

Comment: Could you share more details about how your Beanstalk application code is setup?

Comment: The message "Stderr:npm WARN ..." is missleading. In my case the deployment didn't fail because of warnings, there was some bad configuration of packages that somehow managed to install on my mac but not on AWS's linux

Answer (score 3):

Ended up using a work around by adding a `.npmrc` file and added the line `--logLevel=error`